# python kubernetes watch pod logs not working

Tags: python, kubernetes

Trying to use the python kubernetes API to stream the output of kubernetes pod logs. (eventual goal is to stream the logs out via websocket)

Based off this [PR](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python-base/pull/93) that was merged into python kubernetes module, i thought watch would work with read_namespaced_pod_log?

```
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
w = watch.Watch()
for e in w.stream(v1.read_namespaced_pod_log, name=pod, namespace=namespace, follow=True, tail_lines=1, limit_bytes=560, _preload_content=False):
   print(e)
```

But i get the error below, am i missing something that needs to be passed to watch? or read_namespaced_pod_log?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/watch/watch.py", line 132, in stream
    resp = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/apis/core_v1_api.py", line 18538, in read_namespaced_pod_log
    (data) = self.read_namespaced_pod_log_with_http_info(name, namespace, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/apis/core_v1_api.py", line 18576, in read_namespaced_pod_log_with_http_info
    " to method read_namespaced_pod_log" % key
TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument 'watch' to method read_namespaced_pod_log
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should just do:

```
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
w = Watch()
for e in w.stream(v1.read_namespaced_pod_log, name=pod, namespace=namespace):
    print(e)
```

Comment: Still getting the error, is it the way i instantiate watch?
from kubernetes import client, config, watch
w = watch.Watch()

Comment: Are you using a version of the library with that PR merged in?

Comment: just upgraded to latest, 10.0.0 thanks for the help man, and thanks for the sweet feature in your PR!!

Comment: Interestingly the message retrieval from the stream can crash in `unmarshal_event` with `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` in case an stdout line is a pure int. As long as the line contains some non-digits everythig is fine, but printing 42 is a crash ;).

Comment: Nice catch. Please report this as an issue.

Comment: [Issue to track](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/983)

Comment: I opened a PR to fix the issue: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python-base/pull/171

Comment: more examples here:
 https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python#examples